# Changing an object's type after calling a particular function

Tags: typescript

In the code below can one tell the compiler that after calling `flip()`, `becomeFoo` will change from type `Bar` to type `Foo`?

```js
type Bar = {
    type: 'bar'
    flip: ()=>void
}
type Foo = {
    type: 'foo'
    flip: ()=>void
}

let becomeFoo:Bar = {
    type: 'bar',
    flip: ()=> { (becomeFoo as unknown as Foo).type = 'foo' }
}

becomeFoo.flip() : becomeFoo is Foo
```

[code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgJygXigbwFBW1UkBcUA5AEaJFY4BmANgJZiEAUAlMgHwBuA9nQCYYAvhjzQAYt24p0lbKMJEqkijii0GzNl14DhGGhGBQSEAMbcAthAnd88JKkyr5xMgiIAaWWvqMorDnR-E3MrGyg4AGcoAFcAOwBrOO4AdziI6JsWADpRaUVlKGE9AHoSqDpo4AALCARoODiQKBS4ZuApYAgaGlxaqFCwOgMkGrgjOCoupFM4Hro4gHMfBlYMMuMzS2tJCujklNxwcUkAfgwQ7Zts9TBWKCA)

This seems like a similar requirement to using type predicates ala `function isFish(pet: Fish | Bird): pet is Fish`

Probably a silly question as I assume the answer is no, but one doesn't know what one doesn't know.

Comment: I suspect you can't. I thought you might be able to do it by making `flip` a type assertion function (though I'm not sure I'd've recommended it), but [that doesn't work](https://tsplay.dev/NdAkXm). I'd suggest having `flip` return a *new* object instead.

Comment: I'm still contemplating your question, but in any case I would say `becomeFoo` should be declared as `let becomeFoo: Foo | Bar = ...` given that you are going to attempt to have that same variable store a `Foo` reference later in the block.

Comment: @David P. Caldwell - in my real world code, the object is transitioning state after the function call.  So it exposes different properties - which are not available before the transition.  I'd like the type to reflect this state transition - which is known at compile time and so is not dynamic.  It's not a new object - hence returning a new object would break other things.  I could merge the states with unions, but that also seems wrong too.

Comment: Ah good, well I headed in the direction you wanted, @TrevTheDev - see my answer, which might meet your needs.

Comment: TS doesn’t model arbitrary type mutations.  You can kind of get this behavior by explicitly reassigning union-typed variables or properties, since that “resets” narrowing.  But assertion functions and type guard functions can only narrow.  So you can go from `Foo | Bar` to (say) `Foo`, but you can’t go the other way or from `Foo` to `Bar`.  State is not really something TS tracks or models well

Comment: @jcalz, thank you, yes that's what I suspected.  After some more thought, I created [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXQXoN) example - to show what is a fairly standard use case in which explicit reassignment is not even an option.

Answer (score 2):

This gets you part of the way to where it appears you want to go.

We can (as @T.J. Crowder suggests) return a value from `flip` that contains type information, even without creating a new object. This type information, along with an assignment back to the variable, can be enough to reassign the static type of the variable after a call to `flip()`:

```js
type Bar = {
    type: 'bar'
    flip: ()=>Foo
}
type Foo = {
    type: 'foo'
    flip: ()=>Bar
    canNowDoThis: () => void
}

let becomeFoo:Foo | Bar = {
    type: 'bar',
    flip: function() { (becomeFoo as unknown as Foo).type = 'foo'; return this as unknown as Foo; }
}

// invoking this makes the type Foo
becomeFoo = becomeFoo.flip()

// Now we can use Foo-specific properties
becomeFoo.canNowDoThis()

// no cast needed
let nowFoo: Foo = becomeFoo
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgJygXigbwFBW1UkBcUA5AEaJFY4BmANgJZiEAUAlMgHwBiA9txgL4Y80HtxTpK2YYSJVeFHFFoNmbdvASSoAYzgA7AHLcA7gBFuAFQAWdAM6qU7KADdudACYCMGGhGBQSCG1uAFsIUXxRKAAfWERxTEVpYjIEIgAaLWVGJQBXPW1gOm49VnQoJkDgsKi4Wyh8gGs9Ez0oOqhRFgA6YXFZeQBuKAQ-XIQ24Bt6jqaW4zaO0WHBQQwAenWoOj1XRp2Ac1xpqBC4Roh6qeg+0Qwq0PDecQea3m7s1m9NqCNjKGM0F0bVythEvAAtLZINo6FQ6NooGAENxIAgipd7kFHqJusC-uZrHYvhsti0dHV-HoIBB3LSfH4oPMIp1nqhXk8+EA)

Comment: I considered that when posting my comment, but it has to me a massive downside: `let x: Bar = /*...*/; x.flip();`. Now `x` is a `Foo`, not a `Bar`, but TypeScript thinks it's a `Bar`. The opportunities for incorrect code absolutely *abound*... Somewhere you're going to have a variable you don't reassign when doing `flip`, and it's going to bite you. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  Creating a new variable `nowFoo` doesn't answer my question though.  `becomeFoo` is transitioning state and I'd like the compiler to understand that it's a newish type, with different properties available after the transition.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Hardly seems like this would bite one - it's a similar requirement to type predicates and those don't have a reputation for being a problem.  The only difference is that instead of narrowing from Foo|Bar to Foo, I'm saying from here onward this variable's type is Foo

Comment: @TrevTheDev `becomeFoo` has also acquired the new static type. I just assigned it to `nowFoo` to demonstrate that, not because you need to do it. If you hover over it in the playground on line 17 and 20 (on the right side of the assignments) you'll see `becomeFoo` transitions from a `Bar` to a `Foo`. And if you type `becomeFoo.` you'll see in the autocompletion that (for example) `type` is `"foo"`.

Comment: @TrevTheDev - Provided you only **ever** use `Foo | Bar` for these things, maybe. Compared to creating new objects, it seems *way* more problematic.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder possibly the use case here is inherited JavaScript code which has state and an attempt to add type checking and static type information to it -- I can imagine it being a lot of work ripping all the state out to make it possible to return new objects in response to state transitions.

Comment: I changed the playground to make it easier to see the type change: if you hover over `becomeFoo` on line 19 of the playground, you'll see it's a `Foo`.

Comment: @David P. Caldwell if it wasn't for the `becomeFoo = becomeFoo.flip()` your solution would be perfect.  I just checked it in my unit tests and your solution removed the red squiggly lines without making any other changes.  I'd still prefer the ability to tell the compiler `becomeFoo is Foo` from here forward - but I suspect there is no way.

Comment: OK, I made it clearer yet by giving `Foo` a property `Bar` doesn't have and using it (both in the answer and in the Playground).

Comment: and yes, I suspect there isn't a way to do *exactly* what you want, though I am not certain!

Comment: @DavidP.Caldwell I created [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXQXoN) example to show a standard use case in which explicit reassignment would not be an option.

Comment: True, and JavaScript programmers have dreamed up some pretty crazy behaviors using duck typing over the years, but `becomeFoo.changeStateToFoo = 'Hello, Foo'` resulting in a massive object mutation is ... not very idiomatic JavaScript, to say the least. Even with all the crazy stuff I've seen, I still haven't seen a JavaScript object where assigning to a property radically transforms the object's other properties. So I can see why a type system like TypeScript's wouldn't contemplate it.

Comment: ... but if I encountered such a monstrosity, this is probably the refactor I'd do to minimally wrap the whole thing so that I could proceed -- adding a function that wraps the assignment and replacing instances of the assignment with the function call. See bitly 3zQIzKt (URL-shortened links prohibited in comments, sorry).